# Implementing Location Checkin Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, geolocation, geocoding, checkin

I am trying to implement location "checkins" in my Rails 3 application.

For example: User searches for a place and we can find the latitude and longitude of the that place and allow the user to "check in" there.

Is there a gem that can help to achieve that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The gem you're looking for is 'geocoder' and there is a great screencast about this at http://railscasts.com/episodes/273-geocoder?autoplay=true

Comment: Thanks Nathan. I have given a look to geocoder gem. It is excellent for address to latitude to longitude translations. I wanted a service that can help me find places nearby that users can check in. I am looking at SimpleGeo or something similar to implement this functionality.